# What does (EC2) 'AMI: Unavailable' mean and how should I handle it?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-ami

I'm running two EC2 instances, (Linux and Windows) on AWS, which initiated based on AMIs provided by Amazon. Everything works fine, but since a couple of weeks, I noticed that on Windows Instance, under "Description" tab, it says that "AMI: Unavailable (ami-f0c9ff84)".

I have not performed a reboot on that EC2 for more than a month and I'm curious if everything will work again seamless after reboot. Is "AMI unavailable" a serious problem? Why the AMI is not available any more? I'm not sure if I need to take some actions from my side (e.g. to get an EBS snapshot in case of failed reboot, whatever).

Should I be afraid that restarting the instance will not work while it says "AMI unavailable"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This has meanwhile been addressed in the AWS team response to the identical question asked in the AWS forum, see [EC2 reports AMI: Unavailable](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=325839#325839):

> This is an AWS owned AMI that is no longer publicly available as it is
>   deprecated. This will not affect your currently running instance.
>   Additionally, if you create an EBS AMI of your running instance you
>   will create a point in time backup of your current configuration --
>   which you can use to launch duplicate instances from.
>
> The current AWS provided Windows Server 2008 32bit AMI is:
>   ami-541dcf3d

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer implies, this is not a problem.  It just means that the original AMI used to create your instance is no longer available (so you would not be able to recreate your instance from the same image as you originally did).